# ¿Cómo mostrar un spinner dependiendo de la respuesta de la API?

Tags: javascript, angular, spinner, ngx, ng

ojalá alguien pueda responderme, llevo tres horas intentendolo sin exgerar y por más que lo intento e investigo no lo logré. Mire tutoriales, leí la documentación, consologue para ver que pasaba y nada.

Este es mi problema: Quiero mostrar un `ngx-spinner` luego de recibir la respuesta de la api en Angular CLI 12.2.13.

Utilice esta libreria https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner y la customize utilizando un gif como img. Y bueno,lo que hago es una condicionar que primero oculte el spinner con un `*ngIf` si `this.succes` es false. Una vez eso, llamo a this.spinner.show() en la respuesta de la API para que lo abrá una vez se halla completado la petición, pero no funciona, no muestra nada. Y en consola verifique si el estado del *ngIf esta correcto, lo cual si porque me devuelve un true, también verifique si esta llamando el spinner lo cual también hace. No me lanza ningún error, tal vez alguien leyendo el código se percata de mi error, porfavor si alguien me ayuda

**HTML**

```html
<ngx-spinner *ngIf="succes" bdColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)" template="<img src='../../../assets/gif/spinnerHeartBeat.gif'>" [fullScreen]="true">
  <p style="color: white; position: relative; top: 55px; left: 30px;"> Cargando... </p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

**Llamando la res de la API**

```
  onClickNext() {
    var errorMessage: string = 'Ingrese los datos!';
    var validForm: boolean = false;

    if (this.cardForm.valid) {
      validForm = true;

      if (!this.validCard) {
        validForm = false;
        errorMessage = 'Tarjeta no es válida';
      }
    }

    if (validForm) {
      console.log('this.cardForm :>> ', this.cardForm);
      this.pixelService
        .createOrder(this.pixelPayOrder())
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
        .subscribe(

          (res) => {
            console.log('res :>> ', res);
            if (res) {
              if (res.success) {
                // setTimeout(() => {
                //   /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
                //   this.spinner.hide();
                // }, 5000);
                //this.succes = true;
                //console.log('spinner', this.spinner);
                this.bookingService.eraseData();
                this.router.navigate(['../finalizado'], {
                  relativeTo: this._activedRoute,
                });
              } else {
                //this.spinnerM();
                console.log('spinner', !this.succes);
                console.log('error', res.message);

                //this.openSnackBar(res.message);
                // setTimeout(() => {
                //   /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
                //   this.spinner.show();
                // }, 1000);
              }
            } else {
              console.log('error');
              // if (!this.succes) {
              //   //this.succes = true;
              //   this.spinnerM();
              // }
              // this.openSnackBar('¡Ocurrió un error!');
            }
          }, 
          err => {
            if (!this.succes) {
              this.succes = true;
             // this.spinnerM();
              //this.spinner.show();
              console.log('err', err);
            }
          }
          );
    } else {
      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
      //   this.spinner.hide();
      // }, 5000);
      this.openSnackBar(errorMessage);
    }
  }
```

**Metodo que abre el spinner**

```
 spinnerM(): void {
    this.spinner.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.spinner.hide();
    }, 2000)

  }
```

Porfavor si alguien podría ayudarme en este caso, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Quitale la condición `*ngIf="succes"` al componente y solo usa los métodos `hide` y `show` para controlar el spinner.

Comment: Hola! Utilice el metodo, al final era la forma en la que enviaba la validacion, asi que entonces probe el hide y show y funcionó super bien. Gracias!